# Swift: optional array count

Tags: arrays, swift, option-type

In Objective-C, if I had the following property:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray * myArray;
```

A method to return a number of objects in `myArray` would look like:

```
- (NSInteger) numberOfObjectsInMyArray
{
    return [self.myArray count];
}
```

This would return either the number of objects in the array, or 0 if `myArray == nil`;

The best equivalent I can think of for doing this in Swift is:

```
var myArray: Array<String>?

func numberOfObjectsInMyArray() -> Int
{
   return myArray ? myArray!.count : 0
}
```

So checking the optional array contains a value, and if so unwrap the array and return that value, otherwise return 0.

Is this the correct way to do this? Or is there something simpler?

Comment: Perhaps return an optional `Int?`?

Comment: the optional `Int` is not necessary, because there is a value return value in every case here.

Comment: `return myArray?.count`… yes, definitely shorter. But of course that relies on the result being used in a place where an optional is allowed. No good in `func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView!) -> Int` for example

Comment: @holex: Yes, but "0" seems like a proxy for "error" or "none" or "nil" which is the point of the optional. (But perhaps that's not how it's actually used in this case?)

Comment: @AshleyMills: well, you have to unwrap the optional somewhere, but it's not clear where is best...

Comment: @AndrewJaffe, in practice in ObjC, if the array was `nil` the `count` was `0`. I guess that is the desired behaviour the OP likes to replicate somehow in _Swift_.

Comment: Why do you want to return 0 for a nil array? An empty array has 0 elements. A nil array does not exist. There is a fundamental difference.

Comment: @pasta12 See my comment above re. the `UITableViewDataSource` method

Comment: Only-vaguely-related aside: I really hope that we can start using "[swiftian](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Swiftian)" as the equivalent of "pythonic" for Swift.

Comment: @ashleyMills, I've updated my answer: any reason for having an optional array at all?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Try using the [nil coalescing operator](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/BasicOperators.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH6-XID_124).

According to the Apple Documentation:

> The nil coalescing operator (a ?? b) unwraps an optional a if it contains a value, or returns a default value b if a is nil.

So your function could look like this:

```
    func numberOfObjectsInMyArray() -> Int {
        return (myArray?.count ?? 0)
    }
```

I agree with others that this could be a bad idea for a number of reasons (like making it look like there is an array with a count of "0" when there isn't actually an array at all) but hey, even bad ideas need an implementation.

EDIT:

So I'm adding this because two minutes after I posted this answer, I came across a reason for doing exactly what the author wants to do.

I am implementing the NSOutlineViewDataSource protocol in Swift. One of the functions required by the          protocol is:

`optional func outlineView(_ outlineView: NSOutlineView, 
             numberOfChildrenOfItem item: AnyObject?) -> Int`

That function requires that you return the number of children of the `item` parameter. In my code, if the item has any children, they will be stored in an array, `var children: [Person]?`

I don't initialize that array until I actually add a child to the array.

In other words, at the time that I am providing data to the NSOutlineView, `children` could be `nil`  or it could be populated, or it could have once been populated but subsequently had all objects removed from it, in which case it won't be `nil` but it's `count` will be `0`. NSOutlineView doesn't care if `children` is `nil` - all it wants to know is how many rows it will need to display the `item`'s `children`.

So, it makes perfect sense in this situation to return `0` if `children` is `nil`. The only reason for calling the function is to determine how many rows NSOutlineView will need. It doesn't care whether the answer is `0` because `children` is nil or because it is empty.

`return (children?.count ?? 0)` will do what I need. If `children` is `nil` it will return `0`. Otherwise it will return `count`. Perfect!

Comment: The use of the nil coalescing operator illustrated in this answer is the cleanest solution to the problem as stated by the OP (the best answer).  You could question the API choices, but for legacy code, that is a different animal.

Answer (score 8):

That looks like the simpler way.

The Objective-C code is shorter only because `nil` is also a form of 0, being a C-based language.

Since swift is strongly typed you don't have such a shorthand. In this specific case it requires a little more effort, but in general it saves you most of the headaches caused by loose typing.

---

Concerning the specific case, is there a reason for making the array optional in the first place? You could just have an empty array. Something like this might work for you:

```
var myArray: Array<String> = []

func numberOfObjectsInMyArray() -> Int {
   return myArray.count
}
```

([Source for this information](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=30))

Comment: I like it! And Swift would ensure myArray always has a value. Great, thanks.

Comment: because a nil value indicates an array which hasn't been set vs an array of 0 count.

Answer (score 4):

How about using `optional` for return value?

```
var myArray: Array<String>?

func numberOfObjectsInMyArray() -> Int? {
    return myArray?.count
}
```

I think that this way is safer.

([Source for this information](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=30))